# Распределение и отслеживание нагрузки приложений на нескольких выделенных серверах, а так же управление приложениями запущенными на них

Tags: java, linux, администрирование

Всем привет.
У меня есть несколько выделенных серверов на которых запущены приложения с которыми работают пользователи. Каждый выделенный серверов имеет свои собственные характеристики (Память жесткого диска, ядра и их частота, оперативная память). На каждом выделенном сервере запускаются приложения. Приложение потребляет ресурсы выделенного сервера не стабильно, все зависит от того сколько пользователей пользуется данным приложением в это время.

Каждый выделенный сервер подключен к системе синхронизаций. Которая должна запускать приложения, а так же получать информацию от каждого выделенного сервера (на сколько он сильно загружен и т. д).

Теперь сам вопрос:
Системе синхронизаций необходимо получать самые актуальные данные о нагрузке и количестве потребляемых ресурсов каждого выделенного сервера. Как это сделать? Как можно получить количество потребляемой оперативной памяти, а так же нагрузку на ядра процессора?

Каким образом можно передать максимально быстро данные синхронизирующей системе от выделенного сервера и в случае изменений их, сразу же отправить новые?

Имея данные на синхронизирующем сервере. Необходимо из всех доступных выделенных серверов получить самый не загруженный (По количеству оперативной памяти и нагрузки на ядра процессора ). Как это сделать?

Что бы не создавать кучу вопросов, задам их тут. Как можно получить TPS(Tick per second) на всем выделенном сервере? Имею ввиду не на определенной запущенной программе, а во всей системе.

Все приложения написаны на Java. Работа и получение данных необходимо получить кодом Java.

Comment: Выглядит как то, что вы хотите изобрести свой load balancer(я в них не силён, и не буду предлагать вам какой-то конкретный продукт, но, думаю, что вам нужно капать в этом направлении)